# Get actual volume output from android device

Tags: java, android, volume, meter

I'm trying to get some information about the current volume that's being "output" by an android device.
E.g - when playing a song the output volume would be 7, when nothing is playing the output volume would be 0(this should be the result regardless of the actual media volume level).

I tried looking at the volume library, but I don't seem to find anything that allows me to do that there.
This will eventually be for a TV box, so I can't use a built-in mic in order to try and possibly measure that, I might get a microphone if I'll have no choice though, but trying to see if it could be possible without it.

I know I can get the current media volume of the device/app, but that still doesn't really help me in knowing what is the actual volume output(if there is any).

So would something like that even be possible? And if so, I would love to get some directions on how to do that.

Thanks.